# How to set parameter without ? simbol in asp net core web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a web app with asp net core.
I have the following url: https://localhost:44370/f6ebb97e-17c1-4c50-af83-643d82ded22c
Where f6ebb97e-17c1-4c50-af83-643d82ded22c is the parameter I want to get from the home controller without the need to write in the url https://localhost:44370/?Guid=f6ebb97e-17c1-4c50-af83-643d82ded22c.

Change this: https://localhost:44370/?Guid=f6ebb97e-17c1-4c50-af83-643d82ded22c.

For This: https://localhost:44370/f6ebb97e-17c1-4c50-af83-643d82ded22c

How can I do this ?, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you share us the code for the home controller as well as your current routing setup?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, data for GET requests must either come from the route or the query string. Here you're wanting it from the route, which means you simply need to define the route for that:

```
[HttpGet("{guid}")]
public IActionResult Foo(Guid guid)
```

This is covered in explicit detail in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-template-reference). Also see the discussion of [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing).

FWIW, you should at very least add a route constraint with that, specifying namely that the param must be a valid GUID.

```
[HttpGet("{guid:guid}")]
```